# draw to canvas without regard to DPI

Tags: android, graphics, scaling, dpi

I'm developing a simple arcade game and I'd like to paint the graphics onto a Canvas without regard for the device DPI, just the pixels.
If I do some drawing in 240x320 pixels emulator, I'd like the Canvas to have 240x320 pixels. 
`Canvas.getWidth()` and `getHeight()` tell me that I have 240x320 pixels Canvas, but when I draw a line by `g.drawLine(0,0, 240, 320, activePaint);` a line gets drawn only to (180;240). It's scaled by DPI  somehow, but I'd like to draw to the exact pixels. Is there a simple fix to this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then all you should need to do specify the supports-screens anyDensity=true and smallScreens=true into your manifest. That should stop the scaling from happening.

details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html